How to overcome SharePoint list advanced settings read access
I have this settings on my SharePoint list:

and I'm asking you guys if there is any possibility, to edit items (status field) from external service Navision (Microsoft Dynamics NAV) with this settings ON.

I don't want to break role inheritance and give to the account higher access than "Contribute without delete" (that is set in site permission) - realized that nor "Full control" access will help.

Not with Power Automate flow

I want to keep this settings, because of security.


I'm sending requests through POSTMAN to API with auth type NTLM, but with this read access settings ON it is always 400 status.

only solution that I know is to have Site collection admin permission, but it's not the option

Please tell me that there is possibility to overcome Read Access for this particular account, so he can edit items although this Navision account is not user that created the item.
Thanks.

The Read access of SharePoint list advanced settings are applied for all users in the list, it cannot be invalid to one user.

Yes, I'm aware. That's why I posted this topic for someone who could possibly know the answer.
